# Modify Node stack trace paths for use in Docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code

I usually develop Node applications in Docker containers and bind-mount my source into the container, for instance, at `/usr/src/app`. If the code throws a stack trace, I get something like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
  at parseUrl (/usr/src/app/node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/utils/url_utils.js:6:31)
  at extractClientBaseUrlOption (/usr/src/app/node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/core/index.js:425:42)
  at Object.setup (/usr/src/app/node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/core/index.js:110:20)
  at setupLock (/usr/src/app/node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/core/actions.js:47:13)
  at Auth0Lock.Base (/usr/src/app/node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/core.js:77:36)
```

This is all coold and it makes sense because as far as Node knows, it's running in /usr/src/app. That's what we want after all – that our applications don't know anything about the host.

However, VS Code has a really handy feature where it parses paths in its integrated terminal and allows you to click on them to open the source. This doesn't work inside a container because the path is incorrect on the host. I need to 'rewrite' it (to use the term losely) to something like `/Users/shankie/project/node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/utils/url_utils.js`

Anyone had any luck with doing something similar? I can envisage possible solutions in both VS Code and in Node...

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that's built in but you might have some luck by changing the `Error` prototype:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/prototype

Keep in mind that some of the methods and properties are not standard - see:

- https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html

Or, you may create a symlink in Docker so that you have it run in the same directory as on your machine - that is also some option and no changes to the code would be needed.

Comment: Great, I hadn't thought about modifying the prototype. That's a really good idea. I'll do some work in that train...

I don't think that the symlink approach will work as I'm sharing the code amongst multiple developers (with different paths), but it's a good idea for certain use cases.